# RabbitMQ list limited (full) queues

Tags: rabbitmq, monitoring, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

is there an api/rabbitmqctl call to list full queues? That is queues that are on limit by max-length or max-lengthbytes. Sometimes certain queues reach this threshold and we would like to monitor this.

Thanks

rabbitmqctl list_queues name arguments doesn't seem to show global limits from policies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> rabbitmqctl list_queues name arguments doesn't seem to show global limits from policies

No, it won't, you would have to use `rabbitmqctl list_policies`

You can use the HTTP API to determine if your queue is close to the max. Here is an example output for listing a queue. Note that `messages` and `message_bytes` are in the output, as well as the policy:

```
{
    “consumer_details”: [],
    “arguments”: {
        “x-queue-type”: “quorum”,
        “x-quorum-initial-group-size”: 1
    },
    “auto_delete”: false,
    “consumer_capacity”: 0,
    “consumer_utilisation”: 0,
    “consumers”: 0,
    “deliveries”: [],
    “durable”: true,
    “effective_policy_definition”: {
        “max-length-bytes”: 10000000
    },
    “exclusive”: false,
    “garbage_collection”: {
        “fullsweep_after”: 65535,
        “max_heap_size”: 0,
        “min_bin_vheap_size”: 46422,
        “min_heap_size”: 233,
        “minor_gcs”: 11
    },
    “incoming”: [],
    “leader”: “rabbit-1@nkarlVMD6R”,
    “members”: [
        “rabbit-3@nkarlVMD6R”,
        “rabbit-1@nkarlVMD6R”
    ],
    “memory”: 47929396,
    “message_bytes”: 9984000,
    “message_bytes_dlx”: 0,
    “message_bytes_persistent”: 9984000,
    “message_bytes_ram”: 0,
    “message_bytes_ready”: 9984000,
    “message_bytes_unacknowledged”: 0,
    “messages”: 39,
```

This data is refreshed about every 5 seconds.

Note that you shouldn't hammer the HTTP API with frequent requests, either!